# Providing job parameter via Spring Cloud Data Flow UI

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

There is Data Flow deployed in Docker and a Spring Batch application is deployed as a 'Task' and turned into a task.

I am trying to provide a year job parameter for my task. I have tried using a properties class with `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation like in [timestamp example](https://github.com/spring-cloud-task-app-starters/timestamp-batch/tree/master/spring-cloud-starter-task-timestamp-batch/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/task/app/timestamp/batch). Then I turn this into job parameter via `JobParametersIncrementer`.

```
        @Bean
public Job job() {
  return this.jobBuilderFactory
      .get("job")
      .incrementer(new SampleIncrementer(year))
      .start(step())
      .build();
}

class SampleIncrementer implements JobParametersIncrementer {

 private final Long year;

 public SampleIncrementer(final Long year) {
  this.year = year;
}
public JobParameters getNext(final JobParameters parameters) {
    if (isNull(parameters)) {
      return new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("year", year).toJobParameters();
    }
    if (isNull(parameters.getLong("year"))) {
      return new JobParametersBuilder(parameters).addLong("year", year).toJobParameters();
    }
    return parameters;
  }
}
```

But the job parameter isn't found later in Step.

Is there a way to pass job parameters from Spring Cloud Data Flow UI to execution?

[image: passing year via UI]

Comment: Just to clarify, I want to be able to re-run the job with a different year. So if I have already run 2010, I could start with a different set of job parameters where year=2011.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The job parameters are passed as `Arguments` where you don't need to specify the `--` prefix. For instance, in this case you need to specify `year=2011` as argument in `Arguments` section.